# Escape dollar sign in postfix config file

Tags: postfix, configuration

I have a password for an SMTP relay server with a dollar sign in it. How to enter this into `main.cf` without postfix thinking it's a variable?

I see nothing [here](http://www.postfix.org/BASIC_CONFIGURATION_README.html#syntax) about escaping dollar signs. I randomly tried putting a backslash in front of the dollar sign and double quotes around it to no avail.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Specify "$$" to produce a single "$" character.

http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html